# windows forms timer: is lock required

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have a button on my application whose click event:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     btn_DoMyAction();
}
```

and `btn_DoMyAction` is

```
private void btn_DoMyAction()
{
    //lock (_lock) //--> Is this necessary
    {
        ...
        ... //long code block(I mean non automic)
        ...
    }
}
```

I am calling `btn_DoMyAction` from both click event and from windows timer tick

```
private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn_DoMyAction();
}
```

I have two questions:

1-) Is `lock` necessary in `btnProcessNextBandBarcode_DoMyAction`  (I am asking first question, because as far as I debug, it seems it queues call, and lock seems to be unnecessary)
   2-) I want to skip thread instead of queue on tick or button click

Additional question is:

- if the answer no for first question, if `btn_DoMyAction` is called from Thread(None timer), how should I take action for automicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends on which timer are you using. If you grab timer from toolbox, you're using System.Windows.Forms.Timer. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6),

> This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing.

So you don't have to use lock because `btn_Click` and `myTimer_Tick` are executed in the same thread.

Additional question:
If you call `btn_DoMyAction` from another thread, in gerenal you should use `lock` because it might be called from UI thread and another thread.

EDIT: 
2. Because Timer is executed in UI thread and action executed on click on button is also executed in UI, situation that tick arrive and but previous execucion does not comlpleate cannot occure (because everything is executed in one thread). If you would like timer that start execution  after particular time passes from complition of this action, you should use diferent timer - `System.Threading.Timer` should be ok - you can start timer at the end of execution (when execution caused by timer).

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer, second question, if the previous code execution has not been completed, if next timer tick arrives, I want to skip it, instead of queue it